# Slider made with Animate.css + jQuery jumping last step when repeating

Tags: jquery, animate.css

I'm working on a website that has a section similar to a quiz, and I implemented a simple slider effect using **animate.css** and **jquery** to navigate through the steps, the problem is that in the quiz, when the user reaches the last item of the "slider" (which is the result), there is a button so he can start over again, but in my code, when you click on the repeat button, when you reach again the last step, it jumps to the first one again, as if you had clicked the repeat button.

I wrote a snippet where you can see the problem, to reproduce it, you need to:

1. Click "next" until you reach the last item, in this case, the fourth one
2. Click on the "back to start" button
3. Click next again, you'll see that when you reach the third one, if you click "next" to go to the fourth, it goes to the fourth and then it fades to the first again, as if you clicked the "back to start" button

```js
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
$.fn.extend({
 animateCss: function(animationName) {
  this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
   $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
  });
 }
});

$('.btn:not(.-back)').click(function(){
 var $currentItem = $(this).closest('.item');
  var nextItemNumber = $currentItem.data('item') + 1;
  var $nextItem = $('.item[data-item="'+nextItemNumber+'"]');
  $currentItem.animateCss('fadeOutLeft');
  $currentItem.one(animationEnd, function(){
   $currentItem.removeClass('-active');
    $nextItem.addClass('-active');
    $nextItem.animateCss('fadeInRight');
  })
})
$('.btn.-back').click(function(){
 var $currentItem = $(this).closest('.item');
  var nextItemNumber = 1;
  var $nextItem = $('.item[data-item="'+nextItemNumber+'"]');
  $currentItem.animateCss('fadeOut');
  $currentItem.on(animationEnd, function(){
   $currentItem.removeClass('-active');
    $nextItem.addClass('-active');
    $nextItem.animateCss('fadeIn');
  })
})
```

```css
.slider-list {
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider-list > .item {
  animation-duration: .6s;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: teal;
  padding: 50px 120px;
}
.slider-list > .item.-active {
  display: flex;
}
.slider-list > .item > .content {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.slider-list > .item > .btn {
  padding: 12px 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slider-list">
  <li class="item -active" data-item="1">
    <div class="content">
      1
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      NEXT
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-item="2">
    <div class="content">
      2
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      NEXT
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-item="3">
    <div class="content">
      3
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      NEXT
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-item="4">
    <div class="content">
      4
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn -back">
      BACK TO START
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can't seem to find where the problem is, and why when repeating the proccess, it's triggering the back to start button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your event handler for the back button, you have used `on()` instead of `one()` to attach the event handler for `animationEnd` effectively adding that handler multiple times.

```
$currentItem.one(animationEnd, function(){
    $currentItem.removeClass('-active');
    $nextItem.addClass('-active');
    $nextItem.animateCss('fadeInRight');
  })
```

Changing that to `.one()` will fix it:

```js
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
$.fn.extend({
 animateCss: function(animationName) {
  this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
   $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
  });
 }
});

$('.btn:not(.-back)').click(function(){ 
 var $currentItem = $(this).closest('.item');
  var nextItemNumber = $currentItem.data('item') + 1;
  var $nextItem = $('.item[data-item="'+nextItemNumber+'"]');
  $currentItem.animateCss('fadeOutLeft');
  $currentItem.one(animationEnd, function(){
   $currentItem.removeClass('-active');
    $nextItem.addClass('-active');
    $nextItem.animateCss('fadeInRight');
  })
})
$('.btn.-back').click(function(){
 var $currentItem = $(this).closest('.item');
  var nextItemNumber = 1;
  var $nextItem = $('.item[data-item="'+nextItemNumber+'"]');
  $currentItem.animateCss('fadeOut');
  $currentItem.one(animationEnd, function(){
   $currentItem.removeClass('-active');
    $nextItem.addClass('-active');
    $nextItem.animateCss('fadeIn');
  })
})
```

```css
.slider-list {
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider-list > .item {
  animation-duration: .6s;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: teal;
  padding: 50px 120px;
}
.slider-list > .item.-active {
  display: flex;
}
.slider-list > .item > .content {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.slider-list > .item > .btn {
  padding: 12px 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slider-list">
  <li class="item -active" data-item="1">
    <div class="content">
      1
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      NEXT
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-item="2">
    <div class="content">
      2
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      NEXT
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-item="3">
    <div class="content">
      3
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      NEXT
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-item="4">
    <div class="content">
      4
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn -back">
      BACK TO START
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**However** A simpler approach might be to use the index of the current slide itself to indicate the next slide like this:

```js
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
$.fn.extend({
    animateCss: function(animationName) {
        this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
        });
    }
});

$('.slider-list .btn').click(function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    var $items=$this.closest('.slider-list').find('.item');
    var $currentItem = $this.closest('.item');
    var nextItemNumber = $items.index($currentItem)+1;
    nextItemNumber = nextItemNumber >= $items.length ? 0 : nextItemNumber;
    var $nextItem = $items.eq(nextItemNumber);

    $currentItem.animateCss('fadeOutLeft');
    $currentItem.one(animationEnd, function(){
        $currentItem.removeClass('-active');
        $nextItem.addClass('-active');
        $nextItem.animateCss('fadeInRight');
    })
});
```

```css
.slider-list {
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider-list > .item {
  animation-duration: .6s;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: teal;
  padding: 50px 120px;
}
.slider-list > .item.-active {
  display: flex;
}
.slider-list > .item > .content {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.slider-list > .item > .btn {
  padding: 12px 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slider-list">
  <li class="item -active" data-item="1">
    <div class="content">
      1
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      NEXT
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-item="2">
    <div class="content">
      2
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      NEXT
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-item="3">
    <div class="content">
      3
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      NEXT
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-item="4">
    <div class="content">
      4
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn -back">
      BACK TO START
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Interesting and it works, I'll probably use this solution, however, I'll wait a little to see if someone can explain why the problem I'm having is happening